# Is it possible to return a shape (ellipse, rect etc.) in Processing function?

Tags: return, processing, return-type

I would like to return an entire shape from a Processing function. For example:

```java
void shapeReturn() {
  return(ellipse(10, 10, 20, 20));
}
```

Is this possible to do? I could not find a return type that is suitable for a shape.

Comment: I guess this is not suppose to be tagged with [tag:java] ?

Comment: There are a Design Pattern named Factory Pattern, maybe! It can help you

Comment: @YCF_L would you be able to tell me more about this Factory Pattern?

Comment: You can google it @CoopDaddio there are an many examples for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: beside @AxelH was correct it seems that is not java question can you change the tag please?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Processing does not support the new features that were implemented in Java 7 or Java 8 (or 9 or 10...). This means you can't use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which **might** have helped here.

You could do something like use an anonymous `Runnable` instance, like this:

```
void setup(){
  shapeReturn().run();
}

Runnable shapeReturn() {
  return new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      ellipse(10, 10, 20, 20);
    }
  };
}
```

Or more generally, you could return an object that contains a function that you then call.

Another option would be to use [Processing as a Java library](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java), so you could then use whatever Java features you wanted.

But honestly this is probably a sign that you should refactor your code.